# Why I can't assign this variable to nullable? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I want to make that variable can be assigned with null. But giving'?' seems doesn't work. Please help me find the way out. I'm new to this. Thanks

```
Public Class T3DObject
        Public V(7) As Point
        Public E(5) As Surface
    End Class

    Public Structure ListElmt3DObject
        Public first As Elmt3DObject
    End Structure

Public Class Elmt3DObject
        Public child As ListElmt3DObject?
        Public nxt As Elmt3DObject? 'this line is error
        Public obj As T3DObject? 'this also error
End Class
```

Is there any other way? Please share. Thank you!!

This is the code that make error: NullReferenceException

```
Sub Process(ByRef E As Elmt3DObject)
        While E.child IsNot Nothing Or E.nxt IsNot Nothing
            'code
        End While
    End Sub
```

Comment: Class names cannot start with a number.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. but still, I can't set the variables as nullable

Comment: Isn't it the case that Reference Types (ie Classes) are already Nullable and they don't need extra definitions to be Nullable?  Remove the `?` and everything should be fine

Comment: Yes only value types can be declared as [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: hmm, i see. But, in the next code i use 'while' the obj Is Not nothing and it's error: NullableReferenceException. I research for that error and solution that I found is to add '?' or 'As Nullable(Of....)'. Could you guys help me solve this?

Comment: Do you mean `NullReferenceException`? From the new code, I would _guess_ that the object `E` is coming through as nothing, or one of `child` or `nxt` is Nothing. If both `child` and `nxt` need to be set, change the `Or` to and `AndAlso`

Comment: Why do you pass E `ByRef`?

Comment: yes. i have some object as Elmt3DObject and some of them has null child indeed. I want the procedure process can do something while the child is not null. but, it is error NullReferenceException.

Comment: In that case follow the instructions of @JayV ´s comment. Currently if `E.nxt` is not nothing but `E.child` is nothing and your code does something with child it will throw that exception

Comment: okay. I think I can solve this problem. Thank you all. I really appreciate it.

Comment: How about the issue, is there anything to update?
If the problem has been solved, marking a valid answer will help others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a VB.Net question, but to understand this it's helpful to understand some of how C# works, too. In C#, there is a concept of `null`. You can assign a `null` value to reference types (ie: VB.Net Class), but you cannot assign `null` to value types (ie: VB.Net Structure). Value type (Structure) variables *always have a value* of some kind.

Coming back to VB.Net, we have the `Nothing` keyword. However, `Nothing` is *not a direct analog to C#'s null*. It's closer to match to the C# `default(T)` expression. VB.Net allows you to assign `Nothing` to value types. It's just that when you do, you get the default value for the type.

The `Nullable(Of T)` type and associated language syntax features were designed to allow newer null semantics *for value types*. This doesn't apply to reference types, because reference types *already have a concept of null*.

---

While I'm here, I also see this:

```
Sub Process(ByRef E As Elmt3DObject)
```

`Elmt3DObject` is a reference type (Class). It's almost always a mistake to pass a reference type `ByRef`. You still want `ByVal`, because passing `ByVal` for Classes *still passes the reference*. It makes a *copy* of the reference, but it's still just a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the information!! Really appreciate it.